# Getting the current progress of fit_generator in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to find a way to get the current epochs/steps while training a model in keras. I plan to run it on a separate thread in my program so that I can display something like a progress bar for my UI. I am having trouble with getting the values for it. Is there something like a function that allows me to get the progress of the training in keras other than what is displayed in the console?

Comment: Please don't overuse tags. This problem doesn't have anything to do with `tkinter` so please remove that tag

Comment: sorry about that. it's my first time asking a question in stackoverflow because I just couldn't find a solution.

Comment: you can always assign own class to `sys.stdout` and then all `print()` will use this class instead of sending on screen. You should find (even on Stackoverflow) examples how to redirect `print()` to `tkinter.Text` or `tkinter.Label`

Comment: if you check documentation for `fit_generate` then you see it is deprecated and you should use `fit`. And when you see documentation for [fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) then you see option `callback=` which means you can assign function/class which will be executed every sample or batche. As example they show [ProgbarLogger](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ProgbarLogger) which sends information on console. I think if you add own function/class to `callback=` then you may get information about progress and send it to GUI.

Comment: BTW: There should be links to source code of ProgbarLogger and you would see how to write similar function.

Comment: BTW: if you plan to run it in separated thread and display in GUI (ie. `tkitner`) then you will have to send information back to main thread because most GUIs (especially `tkinter`) don't like to change widgets in separated threads. But you should find 9even on Stackoveflow) example how to use send information to main thread and use `after()` to update widget in main thread.

Comment: Noted, I'll look into the documentation for fit and callback=. I will also check out on using after() to update the widget. Thanks for your answers. :)